# Get the SearchView from Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, view, toolbar, searchview

Is it possible to get the SearchView in the ActionBar by just having the Toolbar object? .

I know that you can get it through the  onCreateOptionsMenu(), but in this case I am just trying to see if via a toolbar.findViewById I can get it

Comment: I think you should use toolbar.getchildAt(index) to get it.

Comment: how did you add it there?

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
             getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It possible to show the SearchView.For this you need to add menu feature such as :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}
```

You need to implement the below code into menu_main menu(it must be stay into menu folder).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/></menu>
```

Hope it can help to you thanks.

Comment: I did that already, my question is more if I have the Toolbar object and the Search has already been inflated , how to get the SearchView from there?

Comment: Toolbar object not fact.you can take the  Toolbar object.You need to add this Toolbar into SupportActionBar..such as>>>>Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  if (toolbar != null)
   super.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);